# Sorting a Ruby array based on part of a string

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I have the following array...

```
[ "global/20130102-001", "global/20131012-001, "country/uk/20121104-001" ]
```

I need to sort the array based on the numerical portion of the string. So the above would be sorted as:

```
[ "country/uk/20121104-001", "global/20130102-001", "global/20130112-001 ]
```

Is there a way to call .sort and ignore the first part of each element so I'm only sorting on the number?

Comment: Which numerical portion? The first? The second? The combination of both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there's a way. You should use a `#sort_by` for that. Its block is passed an array element and should return element's "sortable value". In this case, we use regex to find your string of digits (you can use another logic there, of course, like splitting on a slash).

```
arr = [ "global/20130102-001", "global/20131012-001", "country/uk/20121104-001" ]

arr.sort_by {|el| el.scan(/\d{8}-\d{3}/)} # => ["country/uk/20121104-001", "global/20130102-001", "global/20131012-001"]
```

Comment: This looks great but unfortunately I'm using v1.8.7

Comment: I get undefined method `sort_by!' for #<Array:0x7f7c81762410> (NoMethodError). There's no sort_by! method in the ruby doc http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Array.html

Comment: @user1074981: well, use `sort_by`, not `sort_by!`

Answer (score 6):

Sure, just use `sort_by`.

```
  arr.sort_by do |s| 
     s.split('/').last
  end
```